# iOS Swift game crashing on everyones iPhone, except mine

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been developing a small "Cookie Clicker" style game for a while now and all of the sudden, the app will instantly crash upon opening. It doesn't crash on my own phone that I've been running the tests on, however, anyone that downloads it from TestFlight cannot even open it. It runs perfectly on the Xcode simulator as well.

Out of desperation, I completely backtracked the update that started the crashes (deleted all the new code for the menu I was working on) but it STILL CRASHES.

I don't want to copy/paste the code here because it is 16,000+ lines and I don't even know which aspect could be affecting it. I am using Xcode 11 and Swift.

If anyone has encountered this problem before and knows even where to start looking for the problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I hate this sort of problem.  Could it relate to something library?  Wrong library, missing library etc ?

Comment: You should be receiving crash logs from TestFlight. You should symbolicate those, and they ideally will point you in the right direction. Make sure you're also testing by downloading from TestFlight (rather than running through Xcode), compare users who delete the app before installing (or who have never installed it) vs though who upgrade. A common cause is UserDefaults or Keychain data that is left around or missing.

Comment: Could possibly be related to a provisioning/certificate issue if it ONLY works on your device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the crashlogs from Testflight, re-sybolicate them, and see where it's crashing.  Download them from https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ where you manage TestFlight.  Here's an example:

[image]

Inside the download is generally two files:

`crashlog.crash`  -- this is the actual crash

`feedback.json` -- any input provided by the user when it crashed

The `.crash` file can be re-symbolicated in Xcode as needed and you can see exactly which line caused the crash.